# Can't use assertThat in test case - "The method assertThat(Point) is undefined for the type CleverBrainTest"

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, assertj, junit3

I'm taking an entry-level Java course and have run into an issue that is preventing me from submitting an assignment.

I have to use assertThat in my test cases to satisfy the automatic grader's requirement that I write unit tests. The issue is that I am unable to use the method without receiving this error: "The method assertThat(Point) is undefined for the type CleverBrainTest"

In Eclipse, the error shows up as a red lightbulb to the left of every line where I try to use assertThat. The error also shows up in the testing result when I attempt to run the test.

Eclipse suggests that I use assertTrue instead, and this works. However, the automatic grading system for my class rejects it. It will only accept assertThat.

**Additional context:**

- The class instructed me to set up my test classes as JUnit 3 tests, which I have done.
- I'm also supposed to include certain imports at the top of the test class, which I think I have done properly.
- CleverBrain implements the Brain interface, which is an interface for a bot that automatically plays Tetris based on student-written methods. This is my first time trying to write tests for an interface. I suspect that's why I'm running into issues. I may just not understand how to do this properly.
- For some reason, when I tried making a setUp() method, it did not work. I instead had to boilerplate all my initial setup for my tests in each method. I have not run into this issue in the past, and I wonder if it has something to do with writing tests for interfaces.
- I'm using a Ubuntu-based Linux distribution

I'm including my test case titled CleverBrainTest in the post. Please bear with me as I am very new to Java. Any guidance is greatly appreciated, and I can supply more information if needed. I'm very interested in learning why this is happening so I can address similar issues in the future. Below is the code, I'll also include the trace for the error.

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
import student.*;
import student.tetris.*;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

/**
 *  Tests to measure performance of CleverBrain
 * 
 *  @author My Name
 *  @version Today's Date
 */
public class CleverBrainTest
    extends TestCase
{
    //~ Fields ................................................................
    
    
    //~ Constructors ..........................................................

    //~Public  Methods ........................................................    
    /**
     * Tests brain's ability to place sticks in deep holes
     */
    public void testStickInDeepHole()
    {
        Board deepHole = new Board(10, 24,
            "######### ",
            "######### ",
            "######### ",
            "######### "
            );
        Brain myBrain = new CleverBrain();
        Piece stick = Piece.getPiece(Piece.STICK, 0);
        Move best = myBrain.bestMove(deepHole, stick, 20);   

        // Now call the brain
        best = myBrain.bestMove(deepHole, stick, 20);

        // Expect the piece will go to the bottom right hole
        this.assertThat(best.getLocation()).isEqualTo(new Point(10, 0));
        // Expect the piece is rotated counter-clockwise 0 times
        this.assertThat(best.getPiece()).isEqualTo(Piece.SQUARE, 0); // make sure it's correct
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Tests Brain's ability to choose a reasonable target
     */
    public void testSetTarget()
    {
        Board squareHole = new Board(10, 24,
            "          ",
            "#####  ###",
            "#####  ###",
            "##########"
            );
        Brain myBrain = new CleverBrain();
        Piece square = Piece.getPiece(Piece.SQUARE, 0);
        Move best = myBrain.bestMove(squareHole, square, 20);

        // Now call the brain
        best = myBrain.bestMove(squareHole, square, 20);
        
        // Expect the lower left destination is where the hole is
        System.out.println(best.getLocation());
        this.assertThat(best.getLocation()).isEqualTo(new Point(5, 1));
    }
}
```

The trace for the error

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method assertThat(Point) is undefined for the type CleverBrainTest

    at CleverBrainTest.testSetTarget(CleverBrainTest.java:66)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

**Things I Have Tried**

- Including the jar (or at least what I believe to be the correct jar -- it's called assertj-core-3.19.0.jar) for assertJ in the project's build path. Strangely enough, I haven't needed to do this to get assertions working properly in my previous projects (none of which involved working with interfaces). This did not work. The error persisted.
- Using JUnit 4. I couldn't get this to work, maybe due to user error. I'm not sure if this is a valid fix anyway because the class instructs me to use JUnit 3. This also did not resolve the error.

Comment: Why `this.assertThat`? and not `Assertions.assertThat`?

Comment: The truth is I'm too green to understand why - I was just following my course's curriculum. But your suggestion did fix my problem.

Comment: @GeorgiiLvov thanks for the help. Can you point me in the right direction for some required reading to understand why this worked / what caused the problem to begin with?

Comment: Difference between static and non-static methods, keyword `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, `this` refers the to the instance of the enclosing class which the method was invoked on. For example, if you have the following:

```java
public class Person {

  private final String name;

  public Person(String name) {
    // 'this' is differentiating between the 'name' *field* 
    // and the 'name' *parameter*
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void speak() {
    // Note the only 'name' in scope here is the field, so 
    // technically 'this` can be omitted (and typically is)
    System.out.println("Hello, from " + this.name + "!");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p1 = new Person("John");
    Person p2 = new Person("Jane");

    p1.speak();
    p2.speak();
  }
}
```

You would see the following output:

```
Hello, from John!
Hello, from Jane!
```

Because:

- `this == p1` for the `p1.speak()` invocation.
- `this == p2` for the `p2.speak()` invocation.

Note that `this` cannot be used in static contexts (e.g., the `main` method above) because there is no "current instance" in static contexts.

By using:

```java
this.assertThat(best.getLocation()).isEqualTo(new Point(10, 0));
```

You are explicitly telling Java to invoke an `assertThat` method on `this`, where `this` is an instance of `CleverBrainTest` in this context. But that class does not have an `assertThat` method, thus the code fails to compile. The `assertThat` method comes from AssertJ's `Assertions` class. It is also a *static* method, meaning you do not need an instance of `Assertions` to call it.

One way to fix this is to import `org.assertj.core.api.Assertions` and then use:

```java
Assertions.assertThat(best.getLocation()).isEqualTo(new Point(10, 0));
```

However, you already have the following import:

```java
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;
```

That is a static import. Static imports let you reference static members (e.g., methods, enum constants, etc.) without having to prefix them with the class name. That import is also a star import, which means every static member of `Assertions` is being imported. All that means you can simply do:

```java
assertThat(best.getLocation()).isEqualTo(new Point(10, 0));
```

Without the `Assertions` prefix and it will still work. Though note if `CleverBrainTest` **did** have an `assertThat` method then that method would take precedence over the statically imported `assertThat` method, so in that case you would have to prefix the method call with `Assertions` in order to call the correct one.

---

> Eclipse suggests that I use assertTrue instead, and this works.

There is no `assertTrue` method in the code you provided, so I can only assume it comes from the `TestCase` superclass (which I believe is a JUnit 3 class?).

Comment: yup! this pretty much sums it up. 
TLDR : remove the `this` keyword from `assertTrue(...)`